# what kind of fruit is this?

Tags: identification, fruits

What kind of fruit is shown in the pictures below?

[image: a picture of an unknown fruit 1]

[image: a picture of an unknown fruit 2]

Comment: Could you add some hints here, like where you are, where you got it.  Was is growing local, in a market, etc.  It looks rather tropical, reminds me also of wild bananas I have seen, or from the Midwest US, a paw paw which is sometimes also known as a wild banana.  But location would help.

Comment: A friend bought from a market in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person who bought it said it's cocoa.
You only eat the beans.

Some images of cocoa on Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=cocoa&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj24fCG0-zWAhUqslQKHXy7DR4Q_AUICygC&biw=1439&bih=962

Comment: Okay, I didn't know it was a quiz question...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wild banana, where did you pluck it? In your garden?

Comment: A friend bought from a market in Taiwan.